# Any Trick for remove in my browser "NON SECURE" message?

Tags: html, ssl, ssl-certificate

A password field in my site is causing a "NON SECURE" message in my browser.

[image: Image with the Sample error]

I don't want to buy an SSL Certificate because those are expensive I just want to know if any GURU over here have a trick in his hands to prevent that message in the chrome browser.

Comment: If you don't have an SSL certificate, your entire site will show as insecure. Not just your password field (Note: I did not downvote).

Comment: No, if there was a way for anyone to hide that message what good would it be in the first place? The only way to get get rid of that message is to have a secure page. To quote Reservoir Dogs, "cough up a buck ya cheap bastard"

Comment: [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a non-profit org that will provide you with a SSL certificate for free. It requires you to have command line access to your web server, however (or for your web host to make it available through their control panel).

Comment: +1 for Let's Encrypt. If you do not have command line access to your web server, you can use https://gethttpsforfree.com/ to obtain a certificate from Let's Encrypt. You'd still need to run some commands but those can be run on any system, not necessarily on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get rid of that message without getting an SSL certificate. That's the whole purpose of the certificate, security.

Comment: Thanks brother I know that since the beginning but I just want to remove the "NON SECURE" message. if I remove the password field is still non secure but at least will not appear. you know what I mean?

Comment: That's a 'feature' of chrome that will show a verbose message warning you to not enter any sensitive information on a non-HTTPS website, a password field triggers that **sensitive information** thingy. This verbose message can be hidden through chrome flags on your browser but obviously you can't fiddle with chrome flags of someone else's copy of chrome. The verbose message is enabled by default since the public release of chrome January 2017.

Comment: Thanks brother. Definitely the solution is to find the cheapest SSL Certificate